# How can I get whitespace between tags to not show up?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a menu using anchor tags, and they should butt up next to each other, so related links can be connected with a border.  Here is some example code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        a {
            border: 1px solid #939393;
            margin: 15px;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        a:hover {
            border-color: #111;
        }
        a.collapse-left {
            border-left-width: 0px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        a.collapse-right {
            border-right-width: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <a href="#" class="collapse-right primary">This is</a>
        <a href="#" class="collapse-right collapse-left click">A group</a>
        <a href="#" class="collapse-left hover">Of Three</a>

        <a href="#" class="">I am by myself</a>

        <a href="#" class="collapse-right">We are</a>
        <a href="#" class="collapse-left">a pair</a>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is some white space between the buttons that are grouped together.  This is caused by the line breaks between `<a>` tags.  These line breaks can be removed, and the problem goes away, but the code is *much* less readable.

Is it possible to keep the line breaks but not have the white space show up?

Comment: Actually, I think it is the tabs or spaces at the front of the next line that is causing the white-space, not the line-break.

Comment: You sure about that, John and John?  I just pasted his code into a new doc and removed the leading whitespace, with no change in the rendering.  (Still has a small gap between the grouped buttons.)

Comment: consecutive white space is combined into one on display, so yeah the linebreak on its own would do it too

Comment: Yes, I believe it is any whitespace, including spaces, tabs, and new lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make the boxes into blocks by changing your CSS for `<a>` to this:

```
a {
    border: 1px solid #939393;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: note that this will make the parent div collapse unless you add overflow:auto to it or a clearing div.

Answer (score 3):

Not ideal, but it works and is better than putting it on one line:

```
<a href="#">First link</a><!--
--><a href="#">Second link</a><!--
--><a href="#">Third link</a>
```

Note that I would normally do site nav with list markup to avoid problems like this, but the solution above solves general white space problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think inline elements (span, em, a) flow text whitespace around them, where block level elements do not (P, h1, div).

To create nav bars I usually wrap the links in list items of an unordered list and give the li `float:left` which forces `display:block` and then they usually sit right up against each each other.

Answer (score 1):

No, the spaces between anchors are combined into one and they show up between your anchors since those are all on a "line" together (even though the line spans multiple lines in source). The better way to do this would to be to use a styled unordered list. However, in IE (I think just IE6, but possibly IE7 too), you still get that whitespace with list items.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with lists. The solution I found (and is perfectly valid) was to put the closing bracket right before the start of the next and I guess you can do that with the **a** element as well:

```
    <a href="#" class="collapse-right primary">This is</a
    ><a href="#" class="collapse-right collapse-left click">A group</a
    ><a href="#" class="collapse-left hover">Of Three</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="body">
    <a href="#" class="collapse-right primary">This is</a
    ><a href="#" class="collapse-right collapse-left click">A group</a
    ><a href="#" class="collapse-left hover">Of Three</a>

    <!--alternate way.-->
    <a href="#" class="">I am by myself</a><
    a href="#" class="collapse-right">We are</a><
    a href="#" class="collapse-left">a pair</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Your 'alternative' example is *not valid XML*, as XML does not allow white space between `<` and the tag name. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags . Not sure if the same is true for HTML/SGML, but I would suppose so.

Answer (score 0):

Using a span to contain your sets of links would help reduce the need to place class names on the anchors (not cross browser in that hover doesn't work on IE6 but acceptable IMO):-

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        span.linkSet { border: 1px solid #939393; margin: 15px; padding: 8px }
        span.linkSet:hover {border-color: #111; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">

        <span class="linkSet">
            <a href="#" >This is</a
            ><a href="#" >A group</a
            ><a href="#" >Of Three</a>
        </span>

        <span class="linkSet">
            <a href="#">I am by myself</a>
        </span>

        <span class="linkSet">
            <a href="#" >We are</a
            ><a href="#" >a pair</a>
        </span>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```